# If $R$ is an integral domain and $R[x]$ is an euclidean domain, then $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Is this obvious? I cannot see that this is true. The converse is fairly obvious though. I tried to show $(x)$ is a maximal ideal and try the quotient but failed. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297981/show-that-if-rx-is-euclidean-domain-then-r-is-a-field.

Comment: @Anton, the OP meant a general ring $R$, not the reals $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ihf Ohh, thanks, that was my inattention, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, $R[x]$ is a PID iff $R$ if a field.

*Hint*: Take $r \in R \setminus 0$ and consider the ideal $(r,x)$.

Comment: Oh i see the ideal is the whole ring...... Thank you for your neat answer.